# How to pass pointer to function that passes argument as referrence in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Following is given:

```
void foo(Bar& argument){ ... }
Bar* bar = ...;
```

How do I call an equivalent of

```
foo(bar);
```

?

Comment: ... `foo(*bar);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment

```
foo(*bar)
```

works.

Comment: Thank you for writing an answer in the answers section. Have an upvote. (Personally I always mark an answer I've nicked from the comments section as "community wiki".)